# Change Matplotlib bar chart bar thickness - output is too small

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I save the horizontal barcharts created through a for loop, the resulting bar chart bar thickness is very small and hard to differentiate when I save the plots to a pdf. The number of bars in the bar chart are not fixed per chart created, but I would like to make the lines the same thickness for all the various charts and just have the charts become taller.

I have tried changing `plt.figure(figsize=(x,x)`, but when I do that, the pdfs generated do not show anything anymore and are blank.

Sample chart with thin lines

[image: barchartthickness]

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Please share a minimum reproducible example

Comment: add ``width=5`` or some other number to your ``ax.bar(....)``